# Informatica BDM - wildcard in lookup transformation

Tags: informatica

I have two tables in Teradata database. I need to do lookup transformation i n Informatica BDM there. Lookup condition looks like:

```
table1.col1 = table2.col1
table1.col2 = table2.col2
table1.col3 = table2.col3
table1.col4 = table2.col4
```

Problem is, that in table1, in col2, col3, col4, there can be value '*', which is like wildcard, meaning that this value for example in col3 can be joined to any value in table2.col3. In other words, I need to create lookup transforamtion like code below>

```
select a.*, b.col4, b.col5
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on (b.col2 = a.col2 or b.col2 = '*') and
        (b.col3 = a.col3 or b.col3 = '*')
qualify 1 = row_number() over (partition by a.id order by (case when b.col2 = '*' then 2 else 1 end), (case when b.col3 = '*' then 2, else 1 end))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I somehow figured it out, so I'm providing possible solution in case it would help anybody.

It's not possible do define more complex conditions of lookup in lookup transformation. Even if you choose specify by -> Parameter  and try define lookup conditions. Informatica allows only simple conditions like input_col1 = lookup_col1 and input_col2 = lookup_col2.  More complex conditions like b.col2 = a.col2 or b.col2 = '*' are not allowed.

But in this case it is possible to use joiner transformation where it is possible to define more complex conditions like mentioned before in join type -> Parameter.

This solved my problem. Hopefully it helps somebody.